# Igraph (C) returns bad vertex ids

Tags: c++, c, graph, igraph

I am trying to load a simple graph in the gml format (I can upload it if needed) and the compute its adjacency list and print it for each vertex.

Here is what I am doing:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    igraph_t g;
    igraph_adjlist_t adjlist;
    int num_edges, num_vertices;

    FILE *ifile;
    ifile = fopen("example.gml", "r");
    igraph_read_graph_gml(&g, ifile);
    fclose(ifile);

    n_vertices = igraph_vcount(&g);

    cout << "vertices: " << n_vertices << endl;

    igraph_adjlist_init(&g, &adjlist, IGRAPH_OUT);
    igraph_vector_t *vect_adj;

    for (int n = 0; n < n_vertices; n++)
    {
        igraph_vs_t adc;
        igraph_vs_adj(&adc, n, IGRAPH_OUT);
        cout << "TYPE " << igraph_vs_type(&adc) << "\n";

        vect_adj = (igraph_vector_t *)igraph_adjlist_get(&adjlist, n);

        printf("\nvertex %d n adjs %ld\n", n, igraph_vector_size(vect_adj));
        for (int f = 0; f < igraph_vector_size(vect_adj); f++)
        {
            cout << "node id " << (long int)igraph_vector_e(vect_adj, f) << endl;
            long int neighbor = VECTOR(*vect_adj)[f];
            cout << "nid " << neighbor << endl;
        }
    }

    igraph_destroy(&g);

}
```

but what happens is that I am always getting 0 as an id as if there had been some type conversion issue. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the point here is to use a typed vector like  `igraph_vector_int_t` and typed functions as well,  `igraph_vector_int_size`.

Comment: Exactly. `igraph_get_adjlist` returns a pointer to an `igraph_vector_int_t`. http://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html#igraph_adjlist_get Btw. I also suggest using R/Python with igraph, it is 100 times more productive. (Unless you really need to do your thing in C/C++, of course.)